# Softbricked my device with encryption

Tags: disk-encryption

Because numeric passwords are trivial to bruteforce, I decided to change my encryption password with a passphrase with the following commands:

```
su -c vdc cryptfs changepw newpass
```

To my horror, I discovered upon rebooting that Lollipop only offers a keypad to input decryption PINs, and I have no way at all to type in letters. I have tried using TWRP to unlock my /data partition, but I get this error message:

```
could not mount data and unable to find crypto footer
```

Then I tried using the command line from adb to mount it manually with

```
/system/bin/vdc cryptfs checkpw newpass
```

But I get another error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "__FD_SET_chk" referenced by "/system/bin/vdc"...
```

I'm totally at loss here... Can anyone help me remount this partition?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there were actually three separate issues here.

1. TWRP 2.8.6.0 is broken for my Nexus 4 (5.1.0)

Regarding the following error message:

```
could not mount data and unable to find crypto footer
```

The current Team Win Recovery Project (2.8.6.0) has a regression for some encrypted Lollipop devices.

**Solution:** revert to TWRP 2.8.5.2, which is able to decrypt the `/data` partition properly.

2. TWRP does not provide a working shell for some binaries

Regarding the following error message:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "__FD_SET_chk" referenced by "/system/bin/vdc"...
```

TWRP doesn't seem to set up the shell properly for `vdc`.

**Solution:** Switching to ClockworkMod Recovery provides a working environment for the `vdc` binary.

3. Lollipop ignores `changepw`

The command `su -c vdc cryptfs changepw newpass` had no effect on my device after upgrading to Lollipop (it had worked perfectly on KitKat), and the PIN of the device was still the encryption password.

I hope this helps someone in the future!